# Double quotes in oracle synonym

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, synonym

I have a table `SC.LT_TABLE`.
Because of some bad coding, my program does this wrong request

```
SELECT * FROM SC.LT_TABLESC.LT_TABLE
```

and of course it does not work. The goal is to make this query valid.

I've tried to create a synonym like

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM "SC.LT_TABLESC.LT_TABLE" FROM SC.LT_TABLE
```

and the query works but only if I use double quotes, which are not used by my code.

So the question is - Can I somehow include double quotation marks into synonym? Or is there another way to make that query work?

I know that the whole problem is rediculous but I can not update code right now :-)

Oracle 11g.

Thanks.

Comment: If you take my suggestion, you are basically dumping more poo on already existing poo. Why not cleanup the original poo in the first place?

Comment: I've cleaned the original poo, but unfortunately I can not exchange the poo contaminated code with the poo-free code right now. So I'm just trying to add little more poo to fix the poo avalanche which can be caused by original poo.

Comment: It seems the table was created using **quoted-literal** i.e. double quotes, so you must use double quotes always. No option but to live with it.

Comment: You're pretty much stuck with having to fix the code. Also, if I were you, I'd ensure that your testing practices are improved, so that this sort of thing is avoided in future.

Comment: @LalitKumarB that is not true. In Oracle `"ABC"` is the same as `ABC`. In other words, quoted identifiers resolve to the exact text they contain, while unquoted (like `abc`) resolve to their upper-cased text. So `"ABC"` == `ABC` == `abc`.

Comment: @JiriTousek - only if it was uppercase and consisted only of allowed characters. In this case the synonym (not table) is a quoted identifier and must always be referred to with the double quotes. The problem is the period in the synonym, not the case of the rest of it.

Comment: So the synonym itself can not contain double quotes?

Comment: The synonym can, but when you want to use it, you'd need to include that in double-quotes too.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes you're right, and it is relevant to this question so I should've included that info. However in general it is not true that you have to use quoted syntax if you created the object using that syntax. That's what I was trying to say.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I guess I'm gonna fix it later and write queries with double quotes from now.

Comment: @JiriTousek The problem here is not the case, but the table name itself having the period created using quoted-identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do what you're trying. The identifier `SC.LT_TABLESC.LT_TABLE` in `SELECT * FROM SC.LT_TABLESC.LT_TABLE` contains three segments and will be resolved in that way.

It is well possible to define a synonym called `"SC.LT_TABLESC.LT_TABLE"`, but since this synonym contains the `.`, it can only be referred to using the quoted identifier syntax.

The key point here is that the identifier `SC.LT_TABLESC.LT_TABLE` is first parsed into three segments, then each segment is resolved, and there is no way to make the two segments `LT_TABLESC.LT_TABLE` look like a single segment, because the decision is made before any existing objects are even considered.